# How can train and predict models with custom data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction

I have 2 arrays, one with sizes and one with prices. How can I train or predict or use a cost function (i'm a begginner yeah) so i can predict prices according to a random size?

Maybe i'm confused with the terms but I hope someone can understand. thanks.

Comment: That is just a regression actually. You can choose any regressor and fit it to your data. Then you'll be able to predict any price on any size. How large is your data set ?

Comment: Which regressors can i choose? Both arrays have 14 elements each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a **regressor** and fit it to your data. Once fitted, you can use this regressor to **predict unseen samples**.

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html) is a link that shows all the regressors available on `sklearn`.

Amongst the regressors you could use I can cite : OLS, Ridge, K-NN, Decision trees, Random Forest ...

The documentation is very clear so you won't find (*a priori*) any difficulty.

---

**NB** :

A training dataset with **14 elements** is clearly not sufficient.

Try to find out other samples to add to your dataset.

Comment: thank you! I'll try that

Comment: if you have any other question, I am here !

Comment: thanks, i will try to implement this in python using sklearn...

Comment: regr.fit(xs.reshape(14, 1), ys.reshape(14,1)) , and i got the return : LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False). What should I do nexT?

Comment: ask a new question

Comment: @JoãoVilaça : Ask a new question I'll try to explain in detail how it works and what you should do ;)